# How to establish secure connection string from on premises to SQL Azure Database

Tags: sql, database, azure, cloud

We are using SQL Azure as Database as Service. Our network team raised a concern to open a port 1433 to connect SQL Azure database from our local server through management studio. They said, If we open a port 1433 we are seeing a plain text in network traffic. So, how to encrypt network traffic for port 1433.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Azure SQL Database forces all client connections to be encrypted.**

Certificate validation client side should be used if you want the client to validate the certificate against its trusted repo. This is a security to protect the client and can't be controlled server side.

Regarding SSMS "SQL Server Management Studio also supports certificate validation. In the Connect to Server dialog box, click Encrypt connection on the Connection Properties tab."

Cf "Connection encryption and certificate validation" paragraph at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-security-guidelines/

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply. I agree with you but we can still connect to Azure database with out using "click Encrypt connection on the Connection Properties tab" this option. So, in this case the connection is not being encrypted. How to make the certificate validation all times by default for any client computer from our network while establishing connection to azure database. It means, SQL Azure should not accept un-encrypted connection all times. So, how to make this?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to block non-encrypted connexion server-side. I've updated the answer to reflect that. I'm still looking for a workaround but have not found any yet. I'll update the thread if I have new information to share.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thank you!! If that is not possible what would be the better solution to encrypt the 1433 port.? Do we need to establish site to site VPN?

Comment: Azure SQL Database cannot be connected to an Azure VPN unfortunately. Please note that according to the documentation mentioned in my answer, connection is always encrypted even if the client does not require it. However, the client may not validate the server certificates if it does not require it.

Comment: Please forget my first comment. Azure SQL Database forces all client connections to be encrypted. Always. It should answer your initial question. However, a server cannot force the client to check the certificate, that's always a client choice to do so. I've updated my answer to reflect that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks again!! That's true, Azure SQL Database forces all client connections to be encrypted.  but as per above link it also  say's if the client computer is not validate the server certificate still our database connection through 1433 susceptible to "man in the middle" attacks." In this case client still can access azure database in un-encrypted mode.

Comment: If a legitimate client does not check the certificate against its trusted repository, the risk is that it connects to a bad guy's server. Then the client would be compromised, not Azure SQL Database. Azure SQL Database can't do anything against that.

Comment: Hi Kumar. Does that make sense? Does my answer above summarizes it well? If yes, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Hi Benjami, Absolutely!! But my challenge is I have to show a documented proof to my network team that the any connections through Port 1433 is encrypting and i'm in search. Ultimately If there is no need of validate the certificate all the times, how we can handle all the client computers in an organization. We can't go and tell each and every one to "'click Encrypt connection on the Connection Properties tab" for encryption. I think Microsoft should look in to it and they have to give option to the client upon request to make the force protocol encryption to "YES". Please comment, thanks!!

Comment: "All communications between SQL Database and your application require encryption (SSL) at all times." from the article above is the statement you have to send to them.
If they are working in a network team, they will know what means the second part regarding certificates, which is not related to SQL Database or even Azure.
If you are working as a bar tender not allowed to give alcohol to people under age, you will ask a customer to show his or her ID. It is your responsability to check if the ID is a valid one (according to the list of official IDs you are trusting) before giving alcohol.